# How to convert multipatch file in .dwg format to polygon in .shp format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, 3d-analyst, dwg, multipatch

I have a multipatch file in .dwg format, which I wish to convert to .shp file format.
When I right click on it to export it to .shp format, then all the data does  not gets converted.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

I used 3D Analyst -> Conversion -> Multipatch to Footprint, but no result is shown.

How can I convert .dwg multipatch file to .shp file in ArcGIS 10.2.2?

Comment: Have you tried exporting it as dxf and loading the dxf in ArcMap? Could you share a sample of your data? My advice would to try to recreate the MP directly in ArcMap/Scene/Pro, if you have the original data instead of doing MP conversion and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing similar problems. I found this software called **Arcv2CAD / CAD2shp** on [this website](http://www.guthcad.com/cad2shape.htm).

It offers very quick and easy conversion of either CAD files to shapefiles or the other way round. There is a 15 days fully functional free trial. After that, the full software budle (both packages) costs 240 US$. I'm still testing, but so far I can only recommend these tools.

*Sidenote: I'm not in any way associated with the company that sells this software.*